# Newbie stumped by innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm stumped. As far as I can see from other posts the following should work to replace the contents of the p tags:

```
<p id="activateSubMenuIcons">.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() { 
    document.getElementById("activateSubMenuIcons").innerHTML = "hello";
   }
</script>
```

but no dice. Also, no indication of an error comes up in the console. Would anyone be kind enough to tell me what I'm doing wrong??

EDIT

Ok here's the whole HTML as rendered by Umbraco:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>WSHA</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/wsha-style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/wsha-style-mobile.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Encode+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>





<nav>

  <img id="logo" src="/media/1042/wshalogo.png">

    <ul>

       <li class="current"><a href="/">Home</a>
       <span id="mainMenuIcon" class="fa fa-bars menuIcon"></span>
       </li>

            <li class="mainMenuItem">
                <a href="/about-us/">About us</a>

              <span id="1259" class="fa fa-caret-down menuIcon subMenuOpener"></span>
              <ul>
                       <li><a href="/about-us/our-people/">Our People</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/about-us/who-we-were-and-are/">Who we were and are</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/about-us/our-houses/">Our Houses</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/about-us/annual-reports/">Annual Reports</a></li> 
             </ul>

             </li>
            <li class="mainMenuItem">
                <a href="/being-a-tenant/">Being a Tenant</a>

              <span id="1293" class="fa fa-caret-down menuIcon subMenuOpener"></span>
              <ul>
                       <li><a href="/being-a-tenant/asbestos/">Asbestos</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/being-a-tenant/being-safe-secure/">Being Safe &amp; Secure</a></li> 
             </ul>

             </li>
            <li class="mainMenuItem">
                <a href="/news/">News</a>

              <span id="1305" class="fa fa-caret-down menuIcon subMenuOpener"></span>
              <ul>
                       <li><a href="/news/community-garden/">Community Garden</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/news/football-team/">Football Team</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/news/health-centre/">Health Centre</a></li> 
             </ul>

             </li>
    </ul>
    <br class="clear">
</nav>

<p id="activateSubMenuIcons">.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() { 
    document.getElementById("activateSubMenuIcons").innerHTML = "hello";
   }
</script>





<div id="banner" style="background-image: url('/media/1035/houses-banner.jpg');">

    <div id="bannerTitle">
        <h1>Whiteinch & Scotstoun Housing Association</h1>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="bannerMobile">

    <div id="bannerTitle">
        <h1>Whiteinch & Scotstoun Housing Association</h1>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="subTitle">

    <h4 class="text-centre">A Charity Registered in Scotland No. SC035633.</h4>
    <h2 class="text-centre">Aiming for High Quality Homes in a Desirable Environment</h2>

</div>

<div id="homeContent-container">
    <div id="homeContent">

        <p><p>Welcome to our website.  Please let us know if there is any information you would like to see included which we haven't thought of.</p>
<p>The modules are designed to help you navigate the site, and by clicking on the 'keys' on the left hand side of the module home pages, you will, hopefully, find the infomation you need.</p>
<p>You can opt for a text only version (see top of page), and there is the facility to download Adobe Reader is you want to print off any information and don't have this facility already (see below).</p>
<p>Please contact us using the link at the bottom of the page.</p></p>

    </div>
</div>


        <div id="footerContent">

    <div class="footerContentBlock" id="first">
        <h4>Quick Links</h4>
                <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.banskorental.co.uk/about-us/our-people/" target="_blank">
                            <p>Our People</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.banskorental.co.uk/news/" target="_blank">
                            <p>News</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.banskorental.co.uk/about-us/annual-reports/" target="_blank">
                            <p>Annual Reports</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="footerContentBlock" id="middle">
        <h4>Opening Hours</h4>
<table border="0" height="79" style="width: 272.583px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 144px;">Monday to Thursday</td>
<td style="width: 108.583px;">9am to 5pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 144px;">Friday</td>
<td style="width: 108.583px;">9am to 3pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 144px;">Saturday, Sunday</td>
<td style="width: 108.583px;">Closed</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
    </div>

     <div class="footerContentBlock" id="last" >
        <p style="text-align: right;"><strong>Whiteinch and Scotstoun Housing Association</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: right;">The Whiteinch Centre</p>
<p style="text-align: right;">1 Northinch Court</p>
<p style="text-align: right;">Glasgow</p>
<p style="text-align: right;">G14 0UG</p>
<p style="text-align: right;"> </p>
<p style="text-align: right;">Phone: 0141 959 2552</p>
<p style="text-align: right;">Fax: 0141 950 4432</p>
<p style="text-align: right;">email: wsha_admin@wsha.org.uk</p>
    </div>

</div>


<div id="googleTranslateContainer">

    <p>Translate this page.</p>
    <p id="closeButton" onclick="translateClose()">x</p>

    <div id="googleTranslate"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function translateClose() {
    document.getElementById("googleTranslateContainer").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'googleTranslate');
    }
 </script> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/template2Javascript.js"></script>
    </body>


</html>
```

And the javascript in template2Javascript.js:

```
document.getElementById("mainMenuIcon").onclick = function () {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mainMenuItem");
    var numberOfMenuItems = x.length;

    for ( i=0 ; i < numberOfMenuItems ; i++ ) {

    if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
        x[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x[i].style.display = "none";

    }
}
};
```

Comment: It works fine. Can you create a snippet using `<>` to replicate the issue?

Comment: "In console"???

Comment: This should work ! There should be some other code or DOM generating an error. Are you using `activateSubMenuIcons` only once ?

Comment: `window.onload` is unnecessary in this example.  It should just work fine... https://jsfiddle.net/zbmowzhy/

Comment: @ChrisNeve the Web Console, when inspecting the element.

Comment: @Alistair67 You need to use `console.log();` to output contents into the console...

Comment: I think he's saying "there are no errors", not "where is my output?"

Comment: @3Dos Yes, just the once. Do you want the HTML code for the entire page? I'm using Umbraco by the way and this is in a Partial View but I wouldn't have thought that would make a difference.

Comment: I think that you should show all of your HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: @codemaker - will do.

Comment: There could be errors before this one and thus it's not showing?

Comment: You could try (for test purposes) changing it to <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("activateSubMenuIcons").innerHTML = "hello";
</script>    (maybe even moving it down to just before the ending </body> tag)  In other words, remove window.onload definition.

Answer (score 0):

if you print something in console you have to write `cosole.log()` like

```
  console.log(document.getElementById("activateSubMenuIcons1").innerHTML);
```

and also you prevent `p tag value than += concat with old value`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("activateSubMenuIcons").innerHTML = "hello";
  document.getElementById("activateSubMenuIcons1").innerHTML += "hello";

  console.log(document.getElementById("activateSubMenuIcons1").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p id="activateSubMenuIcons">.</p>
<p id="activateSubMenuIcons1">.</p>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to print anything in the console (I don't think) - I just meant that no errors show up. However, from your snippet I think I have misunderstood how the javascript should work. Setting the innerHTML property doesn't change the source HTML, it just displays the change in the browser, is that right? What I'm trying to do ultimately is insert javascript on to the page which will then execute when an element is clicked. Is innerHTML the wrong way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I apologise for wasting everyone's time. I now realise that I had misunderstood how innerHTML works. I was looking for a change in the source code, not the change in the browser. The reason I didn't spot that it was working was the text was displaying white on white. When I changed the css to make it purple and 200% it showed up and I could see that it does work after all.

I just need to rethink what I'm trying to do - see comment on Bhargav's answer below.